# Read 14 and 16 bits image

Tags: java, apache, bufferedimage

I try to read (in a `BufferedImage`) a **14 or 16 bits image over 1 or 3 channels** (grayscale or RGB). I precise, each color component of this image is stored on 14 or 16 bits.

My code (using Apache Sanselan / Imaging) read the image but each color component is truncated to 8 bits.

```
File f = new File("/tmp/a.tiff");
Map<String, ManagedImageBufferedImageFactory> params = 
    new HashMap<String, ManagedImageBufferedImageFactory>();
params.put(ImagingConstants.BUFFERED_IMAGE_FACTORY, 
    new ManagedImageBufferedImageFactory());
BufferedImage image = Imaging.getBufferedImage(file, params);
```

Could you provide me a code snippet ? I'm stuck for 6 hours and Google does not want to help me :-p

Comment: I can find the Javadoc for Apache Sanselan, but do not know what you're referencing with Imaging.

Comment: Imaging is the new name of Sanselan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay ! I close my question by myself :-P

I finally found a jar of Java Advanced Imaging. JAI solved my problem.

The following code is able to load TIFF or BMP image of any numbers of components with any depth for each.

```
        RenderedOp op = JAI.create("fileload", filename);
        // gets the number of channels (R / RGB / RGBA)
        channels =  op.getColorModel().getNumColorComponents();
        // gets the depth of each component (16 16 16)
        depth = new int[channels];
        for(int i=0; i<op.getColorModel().getNumColorComponents(); i++)
        {
            depth[i] = op.getColorModel().getComponentSize(i);
        }
        // gets the BufferedImage
        image = op.getAsBufferedImage();
```

Thanks !!